# Using Python re and findall to match complex combination of digits in string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Im trying to use python re library in order to analyze a string containing a street name and multiple (or just a single) numbers separated by a forward slash.

```
example = 'Examplestreet 1/2.1/3a/10/10.1/11b/12a-12c/13a-c'
```

I want to match all digits, including positions after the dot and adjacent alpha characters. If a hyphen connects two numbers with an alpha character, they should also be considered as one match.

---

Expected output:

```
['1', '2.1', '3a', '10', '10.1', '11b', '12a-12c', '13a-c']
```

---

I'm trying the following

```
numbers = re.findall(r'\d+\.*\d*\w[-\w]*', example)
```

Which is able to find all except single non-float digits (i.e. `'1'`):

```
print(numbers)

['2.1', '3a', '10', '10.1', '11b', '12a-12c', '13a-c']
```

How do I need to tweak my regex in order to achieve the desired output?

Comment: What if you split the string at the last/first space and split the last chunk with `/`? `example.rsplit(' ')[-1].split('/')`? See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZWnX14). If you need a regex by all means, try `\w*\d\w*(?:[-.]\w+)*`

Comment: You do not match the single 1 as the pattern expects to match at least 2 characters with `\d+` and `\w`

Comment: @thefourthbird your comment helped me to find the solution thanks. if you post it as response I can mark as answer.

Comment: @linus If you make the second word char optional, you would get `\d+\.*\d*\w[-\w]*`. Maybe you can use a bit more specific pattern like `\b\d+(?:\.\d)?\w*(?:-\w+)*` https://regex101.com/r/owpYZo/1

Comment: Did you try this one: `\d[^/]*`? @linus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern does not match the single 1 as `\d+\.*\d*\w[-\w]*` expects at least 2 characters being at least 1 digit for `\d+` and 1 word character for `\w`

If the address should not end on `-` and can only match characters a-z after the digits, and using a case insensitive match:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]*(?:-\w+)*
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match digits with an optional decimal part
- `[a-z]*` Match optional chars a-z
- `(?:-\w+)*` optionally repeat matching `-` and 1 or more word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yEWILc/1)

Note that matching an address can be hard as there can be many different notations, this pattern matches the given format in the example string.

```
import re

example = 'Examplestreet 1/2.1/3a/10/10.1/11b/12a-12c/13a-c'
pattern = r"\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]*(?:-\w+)*"
print(re.findall(pattern, example))
```

Output

```
['1', '2.1', '3a', '10', '10.1', '11b', '12a-12c', '13a-c']
```

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
 numbers = re.findall(r'\d[0-9a-z\-\.]*', example)
```

Comment: this is not working for float

Comment: Add a '.' since OP wants to match floating numbers too.  `\d[0-9a-z\-.]*`

Answer (score 0):

**Using Regex**

Working example : https://regex101.com/r/PDYSgH/1

```py
import re
example = 'Examplestreet 1/2.1/3a/10/10.1/11b/12a-12c/13a-c'
numbers = re.findall(r'\d[a-z0-9.\-]*', example)
```

**Using Split**

Probably you can split the string using `space` and then `/`.

```py
numbers = example.split(" ")[-1].split("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which seems simpler:

```
>> re.findall(r'\d[^/]*', example)
['1', '2.1', '3a', '10', '10.1', '11b', '12a-12c', '13a-c']
```

You can confirm that it works [here](https://regex101.com/r/SVMoZ5/1) (although, I had to escape the slash (`/`) character).

- `\d[^/]*`: Matches any string that starts with a digit and is followed up by any character, except a `/` (stops at said character).